# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/protobuf.framework/protobuf

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, swift4.2

I have created a framework and used cocoapods dependency to share the framework. I can able to install the framework using cocoapod Podfile and can access the public methods but at runtime I am getting the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/protobuf.framework/protobuf
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE2A1E47-21F7-4CD7-A7C3-AE7BD19A6326/VizurySwiftSample.app/Frameworks/VizuryEventLogger.framework/VizuryEventLogger
Reason: image not found
```

Why I am getting the following issue? I have searched and tried all possible solution but none of them are working? Please help me

Comment: Have you ever checked the Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content section in General tab? You should see your framework name on that section.

Answer (score 5):

I know! I know!

Deleting build cache helped me. I clicked “Product / Clean build folder” and then it magically worked! Aye aye XCode gods!

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks! If using CLI, can run `flutter clean`.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9749#issuecomment-620005369:

Firebase is a static_framework CocoaPod and can only be depended upon by other statically linked pods. Add `spec.static_framework = true` to the podspec.